# flushBuffer() not working

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm running a embedded Jetty Server (Jetty 8). I wanted to make an HTTP streaming app. Thus, I have to flush my writer every few seconds (The servlet will continue running).

The problem is that neither response.flushBuffer(), nor response.getWriter.flush() seem to be writing the output to response. (Although, response.isCommitted() returns true) The output is visible only after the servlet returns.

Is this because Jetty does not support Streaming? Or do I have to make some configuration changes in Jetty?

Comment: Servlet filters can do their own buffering too. For instance gzip compression or HTML beautifier as filter.

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem :)

Comment: @JoopEggen you should move that to an answer

Comment: What gzip filter were you using? as they should also respect flushBuffer?

Comment: I believe it's a app-server configuration. Please, see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453508/end-to-end-reactive-streaming-restful-service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet filters can do their own buffering too. For instance gzip compression or HTML beautifier as filter.